# Get certain substring from String java

Tags: java, string, substring

I can have this string as below :

```
String s = "chapterId=c_1&sectionId=s_24666&isHL=1&cssFileName=haynes";
```

or

```
String s = "chapterId=c_1&sectionId=s_24666";
```

I need to get the number ("24666" in the examples).

`String res = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("s_")+ 2)` this returns me the number `+` chars till the end of the string(the second example is ok). But I need to stop after the number ends. How can I do that.? Thanks

Comment: You could do a similar `indexOf` trick for the `&`.

Comment: You could solve this with regex..

Comment: I believe the stars (`*`) are not part of the string, the user just wanted to make it bold but that wiki formatting doesn't work in code sections.

Comment: +1 icza :)
@TheLostMind I don't know to work with regex very well :( Can you help me please?

Comment: @user3796867 - added an answer with regex :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regExp`

```
    String s = "chapterId=c_1&sectionId=s_24666";
    //OR
    //String s = "chapterId=c_1&sectionId=s_24666&isHL=1&cssFileName=haynes";
    s=s.replaceAll(".*?s_(\\d+).*","$1");
    System.out.println(s);
```

***OUTPUT:***

```
24666
```

*Where,*

1. `.*?s_` means anything before `s_` (`s_` inclusive)
2. `(\\d+)` means one or more digits `()` used for group
3. `$1` means group 1 which is digits after `s_`

*Note:Assumed that your every string follows specific format which includes `s_` and number after `s_`.*

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string by the character `&` to get the parameters, and split each parameter with the `=` to get the parameter name and parameter value. And now look for the parameter name `"sectionId"`, and cut the first 2 characters of its value to get the number, and you can use `Integer.parseInt()` if you need it as an `int`.

Note that this solution is flexible enough to process all parameters, not just the one you're currently interested in:

```
String s = "chapterId=c_1&sectionId=s_24666&isHL=1&cssFileName=haynes";

String[] params = s.split("&");
for (String param : params) {
    String[] nameValue = param.split("=");

    if ("sectionId".equals(nameValue[0])) {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(nameValue[1].substring(2));
        System.out.println(number); // Prints 24666

        // If you don't care about other parameters, this will skip the rest:
        break;
    }
}
```

**Note:**

You might want to put `Integer.parseInt()` into a `try-catch` block in case an invalid number would be passed from the client:

```
try {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(nameValue[1].substring(2));
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Invalid parameter value, not the expected format!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
  String s = "chapterId=c_1&sectionId=s_24666&isHL=1&cssFileName=haynes";
  String tok[]=s.split("&");
  for(String test:tok){
      if(test.contains("s_")){
          String next[]=test.split("s_");
            System.out.println(next[1]);

      }
  }
```

**Output :**

```
24666
```

Alternatively you can simply remove all other words if they are not required as below

```
String s="chapterId=c_1&sectionId=s_24666&isHL=1&cssFileName=haynes";
s=s.replaceAll(".*s_(\\d+).*","$1");
System.out.println(s);
```

**Output :**

```
24666
```

The dig over here is splitting your `string` using a `Regular Expression` to further divide the string into parts and get what is required. For more on `Regular Expressions` visit [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm) link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I use a check in the substring() method - if there is no "&isHL" in the string (meaning its type 2 you showed us), it will just read until the string ends. otherwise, it will cut the string before the "&isHL". Hope this helps.

Code:

```
    String s = "chapterId=c_1&sectionId=s_**24666**";
    int endIndex = s.indexOf("&isHL");
    String answer = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("s_") + 2,    endIndex == -1 ? s.length() : endIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sue this regex : `(?<=sectionId=s_)(\\d+)` This uses *positive look-behind*.

[demo here](http://regex101.com/r/nA4eE8/1)

Answer (score 0):

Following code will work even if there is multiple occurrence of integer in given string

```
   String inputString = "chapterId=c_a&sectionId=s_24666&isHL=1&cssFileName=haynes_45";

    String[] inputParams = inputString.split("&");
    for (String param : inputParams)
    {
        String[] nameValue = param.split("=");

        try {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(getStringInt(nameValue[1]));
            System.out.println(number); 
        }
        catch(IllegalStateException illegalStateException){                
        }                
    }


private String getStringInt(String inputString)
{
    Pattern onlyInt = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher matcher = onlyInt.matcher(inputString);
    matcher.find();
    String inputInt = matcher.group();
    return inputInt;
}
```

> OUTPUT

`2466
 1
 45`

Answer (score -1):

Use `split` method as

```
String []result1 = s.split("&");
String result2 = tempResult[1];
String []result3 = result2.split("s_");
```

Now to get your desire number you just need to do

```
String finalResult = result3[1];
```

**INPUT :**

```
String s = "chapterId=c_1&sectionId=s_24666&isHL=1&cssFileName=haynes";
```

**OUPUT :**

```
24666
```

Comment: I've edited, I don't have **, I tried to bold them but I end up with those characters..

Comment: I've changed my answer. Please look at that